# Open links from JSON in system browser - Cordova

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, cordova

I'm trying to open links which come from a json in the system browser (android and iOS)

But the link the function generates is just this for example: 
{{item.addressLink}} instead of bit.ly/xyzxyz

This what i have:

```
<a href="#" ng-click="goToLink('{{item.addressLink}}')">
          <i ng-hide="item.noPhoneAndMap === 1 || item.noMap === 1" class="fa fa-map fa-2x"></i>
        </a>
        <a  href="#" ng-click="goToLink('{{item.link}}')">
          <i ng-hide="item.noGlobe === 1" class="fa fa-globe fa-2x"></i>
        </a>
```

The function looks like this

```
$scope.goToLink = function (url) {
          window.open(url,'_system');
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
<a href="#" ng-click="goToLink(item.addressLink)">
      <i ng-hide="item.noPhoneAndMap === 1 || item.noMap === 1" class="fa fa-map fa-2x"></i>
    </a>
    <a  href="#" ng-click="goToLink(item.link)">
      <i ng-hide="item.noGlobe === 1" class="fa fa-globe fa-2x"></i>
    </a>
```

Comment: Can you explain me why i don't need to bind the variables?

Comment: This is because when inside ng-click="" Angular all ready knows about item.addressLink as you are inside it's model. There is no need to use Data binding, as in {{}}.